pcmcia card in VMWare Workstation 17
I'm using the 17.6.1 version of VMWare Workstation Pro on Ubuntu 24.04.1
I read here text that a pcmcia card will be recognised by Workstation as a USB device.
In my setup above, I can plug in a USB flash stick, and the VM recognises the fact and when I unmount the device from Ubuntu, the VM can use it. So, the basic USB side of things is working as I expect. When I plug the pcmcia adapter containing a CF card, this registers with Ubuntu as a device that can be mounted or unmounted like a USB stick, and I can read or write to it. However, it is not recognised by VMWare workstation as a USB device or any other device that I can disconnect from the host and use in the VM. I should also state that the pcmcia card is inserted into a PCI card. I'd be grateful for any insight on why this stated sharing of pcmcia card with a vm isn't working for me.
(I know a CF card can be simply read in a USB adapter, but I have another card I wish to pass to the VM and at this point I am just testing the basics.)
Thanks
